# wget in docker prints thousands of lines to show progress instead of a single line progress bar

Tags: docker, wget

When I `wget` a file, e.g. from GitHub, it shows a nice one-line progress bar like that:

```
wget -N http://db.sqlite.zip
db.sqlite.zip   28%[====>                       ]  68.79M   370KB/s    eta 5m 53s
```

But if I run the  `wget` command exactly the **same** way when starting up a container, as a bash script to get some data, it prints thousands of lines, apparently for each 50K bits which are downloaded:

```
app_1  |      0K .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  212K 19m12s
app_1  |     50K .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  426K 14m22s
app_1  |    100K .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 38.4M 9m37s
app_1  |    150K .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  430K 9m35s
app_1  |    200K .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 33.9M 7m41s
...
```

+ many... many more of these lines (it actually fills the stdout buffer and I don't want to).

How could I get the same behaviour, e.g. displaying a one-line progress bar, than on my host machine? If possible of course. Otherwise I simply `-q` it and that's over.

Answer (score 7):

During build docker does not allocate a tty. This will make `wget` fall back to the `dot` display method for progress bars.

Sadly, there is no straightforward solution to your problem. Following a few suggestions:

- Force the `bar` method:

```sh
wget \
  --no-verbose --show-progress \
  --progress=bar:force:noscroll \
  url
```

*NOTE*: this will most likely still produce quite a few lines of output.

- Make the `dot` method print lines less often:

```sh
wget \
  --no-verbose --show-progress \
  --progress=dot:mega \
  url
```

- Write some custom scripts which transform the output of `wget` to what you want.

Comment: `--progress=dot:giga` is an option for the cases when `mega` is not enough

Comment: Would be possible to output just the saved line?